# Numpy savetxt heterogenous data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have two arrays A and B such that:

A.shape is (N, 1) and dtype is int.
B.shape is (N, M) and dtype is float.

The array A contains the ids/serial no. info. I want to write A and B in a `single file with their dtypes preserved` such that each line contains A[i] and B[i, :] i.e.

```
A[0], B[0, 0], B[0, 1], ..... , B[0, M-1]
A[1], B[1, 0], B[1, 1], ..... , B[1, M-1]
.
.
.
and so on.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @wwii I tried concatenating A and B into one such that A becomes the first column of the new matrix but the int dtype gets converted to float.

Comment: Oops... after rereading the question, I see that `A` is int, so see @HYRY's answer.  I wrote my answer thinking `A` might contain strings.  My answer will still work, but HYRY's is much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `fmt="%g"` when calling `savetxt()`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)
b = np.random.rand(10, 3)

v = np.hstack((a[:,None],b))

import io

t = io.BytesIO()

np.savetxt(t, v, fmt="%g", delimiter=",")
print t.getvalue()
```

here is the output:

```
58,0.565189,0.865103,0.508969
23,0.916723,0.921158,0.0831125
59,0.277719,0.0093567,0.842342
2,0.647174,0.841386,0.26473
98,0.397821,0.552821,0.16494
62,0.369808,0.146442,0.569618
35,0.703737,0.288476,0.433288
94,0.756107,0.396098,0.896038
67,0.638921,0.891554,0.680056
82,0.449198,0.978571,0.116202
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what the variable `t` is?

Comment: You can consider `t` as a file in memory.

Answer (score 2):

(I read the question too quickly, and missed that `A` an integer array.  The following is probably overkill, but I'll leave it here in case someone needs to mix strings and floats.)

If the arrays were the same data type, you could concatenate them, and `savetxt` would work just fine.  That won't work if `A` is an array of, say, strings.  To get `savetxt` to print this heterogeneous data to a file, you'll need to use a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html).  Here's one way to do it.

The idea is to create a structured array whose first field is a string
(to hold the ids), and whose remaining M fields are floating point.
To make it easy to fill this array with the given arrays, we'll do it
in two steps.

First, we'll create a structured array whose first field is a string
and whose second field is itself an array of M floating point values.
This data type is `dt2` in the script, and the corresponding array is
`data2`.  This allows us to fill the array with `a` and `b` using the
simple assignments `data2['a'] = a` and `data2['b'] = b`.

Next we create a *view* of this array, called `data` in the script, 
using the data type `dtall` with `M+1` fields.  The first field is a
string, and the rest are floating point.

Now we can write `data` to a file using `savetxt`. To provide a format
for the first field that is different from the rest, we'll build a
complete format string for the entire row, and give it as the `fmt`
argument of `savetxt`.

```
import numpy as np

# Example data.
a = np.array(['A001', 'A019', 'A344', 'A742'])
b = np.linspace(0, 1, 16, endpoint=False).reshape(4,4)

# Create a data dtype with two fields.  The first field has the same
# data type as `a`.  The second has the same fundamental data type as `b`,
# repeated N times.  If you print dt2 using the above data, you'll see
#  [('a', 'S4'), ('b', '<f8', (4,))]
dt2 = np.dtype([('a', a.dtype.str)] +
               [('b', b.dtype.str, b.shape[1])])

# Create an empty array using `dt2`, and fill it with `a` and `b`.
data2 = np.empty(len(a), dtype=dt2)
data2['a'] = a
data2['b'] = b

# Create a data type with N+1 fields.  If you print `dtall`, you'll see
#  [('a', 'S4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')]
dtall = np.dtype([('a', a.dtype.str)] + b.dtype.descr*b.shape[1])

# Create a view of the same data, but with data type `dtall`.
data = data2.view(dtall)

# Create the format string to be used in `savetxt`.
id_fmt = '"%s"'   # The format of the id.
float_fmt = '%f'  # The floating point format.
fmt = id_fmt + b.shape[1] * (',' + float_fmt)

# Finally, save the data.
np.savetxt('ab.csv', data, fmt=fmt)
```

Here's the contents of the output file:

```
"A001",0.000000,0.062500,0.125000,0.187500
"A019",0.250000,0.312500,0.375000,0.437500
"A344",0.500000,0.562500,0.625000,0.687500
"A742",0.750000,0.812500,0.875000,0.937500
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require saving the arrays to plain text, I would also think about using [`np.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html), which would allow you to save both arrays in a single binary file. There is also a compressed version available through `savez_compressed`. Personally, I often save multiple arrays to hdf5 using h5py, but `np.savez` provides a simple interface, which is built-in to numpy so it doesn't require any additional dependencies.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)
b = np.random.rand(10, 3)
np.savez('data.npz', a=a, b=b)

# Now load the data back in
data = np.load('data.npz')

a_loaded = data['a']
b_loaded = data['b']

In [9]: a_loaded.dtype
Out[9]: dtype('int64')

In [10]: b_loaded.dtype
Out[10]: dtype('float64')
```